# Discrete Poincare Inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

For the sake of this question, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ be a regular domain. In variational problems involving the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ (or $BV(\Omega)$) one often uses the Sobolev inequality

$||u||_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)} \leq C ||\nabla u||_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)}$

or the Poincare inequality

$||u - \tilde{u}||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C ||\nabla u||_{L^1(\Omega)}$

where $\tilde{u} = \int_{\Omega} u \ dx$.

It is not so hard to prove the Poincare inequality via contradiction. For particular domains $\Omega$ (e.g. disc, polygon) one can also exhibit direct proofs that give either the optimal $C$ and something not too far from optimal.

My question is this: has there been any work on "discrete Poincare inequalities" of the type

$||u - Pu||_2 \leq C ||Du||_1 $

where $D: R^n \to R^m$ is some linear transformation and $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto its kernel.

For what it's worth, for general $D$ one can prove
$||u-Pu||_2 \leq \frac{\sqrt{m}}{\min \sigma_i} ||Du||_1$ via the singular value decomposition of $D$ (here the minimum is over the nonzero singular values of $D$). But this is not taking into account any special properties of $D$ (e.g. block toeplitz, block circulant, etc) and is not as strong as I would like (specifically, the $\sqrt{m}$ factor).

The situation I have in mind is when $D$ is some finite difference matrix (although perhaps nonstandard). For standard finite differences on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ it is not too hard to show directly

$||u||_{L^2(\mathbb{Z}^2)} \leq C ||Du||_{L^1(\mathbb{Z}^2)}$

in a manner analogous to the classical proof. The discrete Poincare inequality would be more work (and the constant there would depend on the boundary conditions of the difference operator). But really, I would also like this to work for e.g. centered finite differences, or finite difference kernels with higher order of approximation. Is there any literature on this sort of thing?

Comment: Discrete Poincare inequalities are usually studied in the context of functions defined on a graph, where $D$ can be the difference operator assigning to each edge the difference of values at two incident  vertices. The way you stated the inequality is quite general. There is a loss of $\sqrt{m}$ even if $D$ is the identity matrix. Also, I'd say that dependence on $m$ is natural here, since it plays the role of the size of the domain of the function. In the ordinary P.I., the constant also depends on the domain, and scales in the same way.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. But for example, in the case of a forward difference operator $D$ the size of the domain also comes in via the singular values of $D$ (the smallest of which scales like $\pi/\sqrt{n}$, in this case).


In the graph theoretic context the inequalities seem to involve differences along edges. I guess what I am looking for would be some analogue with larger cliques.

Comment: Is there any reason to insist on using the $1$-norm on the right hand side? The Poincare inequality is quite useful in its weaker ``$(2,2)$'' form too, where on the right one takes the $L^2$ norm of gradient.

Comment: Yes, the 1-norm is essential in this case. I am basically interested in studying discrete optimization problems of the form 

$\min_x f(x) + ||Dx||_1$

where $f$ is some smooth function. These arise in a number of circumstances: in signal processing, $D$ being finite differences is the so-called "Total Variation Regularization" method for solving inverse problems. Related problems take $D$ to be e.g. a wavelet transform, or some general dictionary for sparse representation. In statistics, these 1-norm optimization problems come up in lasso, fused lasso, and elastic net least squares.

Comment: And in particular, stability analysis (in the infinite dimensional limit) would involve something equivalent to to the Poincare inequality I mentioned.

Comment: Somehow, the numerical analysis sources I've checked are content with $(2,2)$ inequality, for stability analysis too. E.g., [page 16 here](http://www.ima.umn.edu/~arnold//8445.f11/notes.pdf). (I searched for "poincare inequality" "finite difference" "numerical")

Comment: Well, the (2,2) inequality is completely appropriate for the numerical analysis of linear PDE. Basically, the problem of solving a linear equation is equivalent to minimizing a quadratic energy, and this then determines the sort of inequalities that you must bring to bear. 

But I am not solving PDEs. I am dealing directly with non-quadratic minimization problems. So this is why I am asking for the 1-norm version of the inequality.